# Cobbler reposync failure

Tags: linux, centos7, repository, cobbler

I'm trying to add the CentOS7 repository to cobbler via reposync. I've added the mirror information to the cobbler web interface with the following settings:

```
Arch: x86_64
Breed: yum
Mirror: http://mirror.as29550.net/mirror.centos.org/7/
Name: Centos7 
Owners: admin
```

When I run:

```
cobbler reposync --only="Centos7"
```

The reposync fails with the following output:

```
task started: 2016-07-25_164113_reposync
task started (id=Reposync, time=Mon Jul 25 16:41:13 2016)
hello, reposync
run, reposync, run!
creating: /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/Centos7/.origin/Centos7.repo
running: /usr/bin/reposync -l -n -d --config=/var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/Centos7/.origin/Centos7.repo --repoid=Centos7 --download_path=/var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror -a x86_64
received on stdout: 
received on stderr: Error setting up repositories: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Centos7. Please verify its path and try again

Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'cobbler reposync failed'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 129, in die
    raise CX(msg)

Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'cobbler reposync failed'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 125, in run
    self.sync(repo)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 169, in sync
    return self.yum_sync(repo)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 402, in yum_sync
    utils.die(self.logger,"cobbler reposync failed")
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 137, in die
    raise CX(msg)

reposync failed, tries left: 0
reposync failed, retry limit reached, skipping
running: chown -R root:apache /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/Centos7
received on stdout: 
received on stderr: 
running: chmod -R 755 /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/Centos7
received on stdout: 
received on stderr: 
Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'overall reposync failed, at least one repo failed to synchronize'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 129, in die
    raise CX(msg)

Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'overall reposync failed, at least one repo failed to synchronize'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/remote.py", line 89, in run
    rc = self._run(self)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/remote.py", line 248, in runner
    3), name=name, nofail=nofail, logger=self.logger)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/api.py", line 808, in reposync
    return reposync.run(name)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 154, in run
    utils.die(self.logger,"overall reposync failed, at least one repo failed to synchronize")
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 137, in die
    raise CX(msg)

!!! TASK FAILED !!!
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be here?
Thanks